# Sell rotting apples in time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am stuck regarding the following question. Do you have an idea? Of course, brute-forcing all permutations solves the problem. However, is there another approach?

Suppose you sell apples and each apple has an associated "time to rot" until it cannot be sold anymore.

Suppose also that all apples have a separate price dependent on their aesthetics. The price is constant until the apple has rotten, then it becomes zero.

Selling an apple takes some constant time, therefore you cannot sell them all but only the first k apples.

In which order should you sell your slowly rotting apples in order to maximize your outcome?

Do you have any hints which type of literature could help here? Like operations research or queueing theory?

Comment: This might be a better fit for the [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site (it's definitely off-topic here), but even then you'd have to make _some_ effort.

Comment: I would think that putting them all in a list that's sorted by increasing "time left", and then selling from the top of the list (first-match on the other criteria), would be a useful, if not completely ideal, starting point...

Comment: Is time discrete? Can you only sell one apple per time unit?

Comment: This feels like an instance of the [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Comment: @twalberg It is certainly not ideal. Consider you can only sell one apple per time unit, apples with increasing value and the following "time to rot": 1, 1, 2, 2. It is certainly best to sell the two last apples first.

Comment: Are you given times at which you will have to sell each apple or are they unknown. If times at which you sell are unknown, than this is a stochastic problem and is definitely for math size.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort. @Riko, I can sell instantly. It just takes some time until I can sell the next one (purchase duration). No, I don't see a reason why it should be time discrete ... do you?

Comment: I will have a look at the knacpsack problem, although I don't know how to include the time constraint. Never heard of it before!

Comment: It's an instance of [`Pm||sum wjUj`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_theoretic_scheduling_problems).

Answer (score 4):

I think a simple dynamic programming will work:

```
T(i, j) = 0 #if i>|apples|
T(i, j) = T(i+1, j) #if j/k >= rot(i)
T(i, j) = max(value(i) + T(i+1, j+1), T(i+1, j)) #if j/k < rot(i)
```

With `T(i, j)` meaning maximum profit selling up to the i-th apple after selling j apples.

In each DP step you have to choose the best between selling or not selling the current apple. If the amount of sold apples so far (`j`), divided by the number of apples you can sell by time unit (`k`) reaches the apple's "time to rot" (`rot(i)`), it cannot be sold.

One trick here is that you have to sort the apples by "time to rot" first.

---

### Correctness

I'll paste Ilmari Karonen's comment here because it explains the algorithm correctness and shouldn't be just a comment.

> Note that the correctness of this solution depends crucially on the observation that, if a certain subset of the apples can be sold at all, it can be sold in ascending order by expiry time. Thus, if you consider all the apples in ascending order by expiry time, the only decision you need to make for each apple is whether to sell it now or to not sell it at all

---

### Implementation

Here's a simple recursive implementation in Python (that can easily be memoized for polynomial time):

This program also explains which apples must be chosen to maximize the outcome:

```py
A = [(2, 3), (1, 1), (3, 4), (1, 2)]

def solve(A, k, i, j):
    if i>=len(A): return (0, [])
    ttr, value = A[i]
    if j/k >= ttr:
        return solve(A, k, i+1, j)
    else:
        answer, explanation = solve(A, k, i+1, j+1)
        return max((value+answer, [A[i]]+explanation), solve(A, k, i+1, j))

print solve(sorted(A), 1, 0, 0)
```

This outputs:

```
(9, [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
```

Comment: +1. Note that the correctness of this solution depends crucially on the observation that, if a certain subset of the apples can be sold at all, it can be sold in ascending order by expiry time. Thus, if you consider all the apples in ascending order by expiry time, the only decision you need to make for each apple is whether to sell it now or to not sell it at all.

Comment: I can't figure out what `i`, `j` and `k` represent here. All of them seem to count a number of apples, but somehow `j/k` must correspond to a time. Could you clarify this? Also, when you say "up to the `i`th apple", do you mean the apples between the `i`th and the last apple?

Comment: I explain this this in the text, but in other words: `i` is the current apple we are deciding if we sell or not, `j` is how many apples we have already sold, and `k` is from OP's question, meaning how many apples we can sell by unit of time. `j/k` means how many units of time have elapsed to sell `j` apples.

Answer (score 2):

First sort your apples by time-to-rot.

If the slowest rotting apple takes X time-units to rot, then start from X and work toward 0 time-units.  ([Ben Voight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) observes that you actually only need `min(time-to-sell-all-apples,time-until-last-apple-rots)`)

For each time-unit, select the most expensive apple that isn't yet rotted that wasn't previously selected, and mark it to be sold during this time unit.  If there are no unselected apples unrotted, immediately jump to the time-unit of the next-slowest-rotting apple.

You now have a list of time-units from 0 to X, and an apple associated with each one.  Sell the apples in this order.

I *think* this is optimal, but I'm not certain.  It's a little counter-intuitive, because you choose which apple to sell at which time in the *opposite order that they're actually sold in*.

---

If these are your apples:

```
Index  1   2   3
Price  1  20  30
Time   1   3   3
```

Then we select an apple for each time slot from three to zero.

- First is time-3.  The non-selected apples here are #2 (worth 20) and #3 (worth 30)  We select #3 (because it's worth more) to be sold at time-3.
- The next time slot is time-2.  There's only one non-selected apple not rotted here - #2 (worth 20), so we select it to be sold at time-2.
- The next time slot is time-1.  There's only one non-selected apple not rotted here - #1 (worth 10), so we select that apple to be sold at time-1.
- The final time slot it time-0.  There's no apples left, so we sell nothing at time-0.

I assume for my sample that that there is a zero time-slot, and that the apples rot *after* that time expired, but neither of these are required for the *algorithm* to work, they just alter the implementation.

Comment: Can't see an error in this solution. The only problem is the complexity O(X), that is only pseudo-polynomial.

Comment: @JuanLopes: Complexity is `O(num-time * num_apples)` unless you come up with a crafty trick to find the most expensive non-rotted apple (which can be done, and brings this down to `O(num-time * log(num_apples))` )

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are implying that is only necessary to iterate in the distinct time units declared in the input. But if you do so, the following case won't be correct: [(value=1, time=1), (value=20, time=3), value=30, time=3)]

Comment: @JuanLopes: I didn't mean that at all :(.  I said to iterate from X time-units to 0 time-units.  Not sure how to reword that to be clearer.  Definitely need to calculate _all_ time units, not just the ones where apples expire.  Oh!  I'll add an example.  That'd help a ton.  I'll add your example.

Comment: But what if I have an apple with (value=100, time=1 trillion). Would it iterate from 1 trillion to zero?

Comment: Humm, this seems to work. But, please, make it explicit in the algorithm, because this is the difference between a truly polynomial algorithm and a pseudo-polynomial (exponential) one. (I mean, you only need log(X) bits to express X, so if your algorithm grows linearly with X, it is actually exponential).

Comment: @JuanLopes; After thinking about it more, you're right.  I've added the skip explicitly to the algorithm.

Comment: This is not optimal.  Suppose you have 5 apples that have time 5 and price 1, and one apple with time 6 and price 10, then the optimal solution is to sell the 5 cheap apples first, then the expensive one.

I believe the optimal solution is to sell each apple as *late* as possible.  With clever data structures I think you can arrange to find whether a given apple can be sold before rotting in log time.

Comment: @btilly: That's exactly what my algorithm does!  First, it checks time 6, and selects the 10-price apple to be sold at that time.  Then it checks time 5, and selects a 1-price apple to be sold at that time.  And on down to time 0.   Leading to the optimal solution.

Comment: @Juan: First, discard all apples with negative lifetime, and set X = min(time needed to sell all apples, lifetime of slowest rotting apple).  Then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that time is discrete and that you can only sell one apple per time unit, I think the following algorithm would do the trick.

Sort the apples in order of decreasing value. Now, label the apples `[1,N]`.

Let the apples rot in time `R1, R2, R3, ...`

Let the apples have value `V1, V2, V3, ...`

Construct an array `S1, S2, S3, ...`. This is the order in which you will sell each apple.

Take the most expensive apple. Sell this apple at time `R1`. If you sell the apple at any later point, it will have no value. If you sell the apple at any earlier point, you may be selling it at a time when you could have sold a different apple and selling both apples has more value than selling only one apple.

Consider the apple with the second highest value. If `R2` is not `R1`, then sell the apple at time `R2`. If `R2` is equal to `R1`, then sell this apple at time `R2-1`. This way, we are still selling the apple *as late as possible* to keep our options open, but still prioritizing the apples by value (`V2` over `V3`, and `V1` over `V2`).

Perform the above for all of the apples. If there is no time slot in which to sell an apple, that means only more valuable apples are being sold during that time, which is the better choice.

In pseudocode:

```
Object Apple:
  V - Value of Apple
  R - Rot time
Let Apples[N] be an array of type Apple
Let S[N] be an integer array initialized to -1
Sort Apples in order of decreasing V.

Foreach i in [0,N):
  for j=Apples[i].R to 0 by -1
    if S[j]==-1:
      S[j]=i
      break
```